# Tiny MCE replace " by &quot; in <a>

Tags: javascript, regex, tinymce, wysiwyg, fckeditor

I've tried many things to do that:

`entity_encoding : "raw", "names" or "numeric"` did not help.

```
preformatted : false
verify_html : false
apply_source_formatting : false
entities : "160,nbsp,38,amp,34,quot,162,cent,8364,euro,163....
cleanup: flase did not help neither.
```

I would like `<a href="url">` to become `<a href=&quot;url&quot;>` in html code.

I know it is not W3C valid, i know too that tiny mce might not be the best way to do that, i just ask if someone knows how to do that.

Do i have to use regex ? replace ? What kind of synthax should i use ?

Answer (score 2):

This isn't pretty, but in your init, try:

```
tinymce.EditorManager.init({
   preformatted : false
   verify_html : false,
   onchange_callback : function(inst){
        var $inst = $('#'+inst.id);
        $inst.val($inst.val().replace('"','&quot;'));
   },
});
```

or

```
tinymce.EditorManager.init({
   preformatted : false
   verify_html : false,
   onchange_callback : function(inst){
   inst.setContent(inst.getContent({format : 'raw'}).replace('"','&quot;'), {format : 'raw'});
    },
});
```

Comment: Could you tell me where to add this ?

Comment: Updated answer with detail on where to put it

Comment: Thank you very much Max, i'm sorry i'm not sur, i use tiny mce as a modx addon. See the last answer, do you tink i should insert your code in this file ?

Comment: Where were you putting `entity_encoding : "raw", "names" or "numeric"` before?

Answer (score 0):

```
Tiny.Editor = function(config) {
    config = config || {};
    config.tinyConfig = config.tinyConfig || Tiny.config;
    config.tinyConfig = config.tinyConfig || {};
    Ext.applyIf(config.tinyConfig,{
        setup: (function(ed) {
            ed.onInit.add(this.onLoad);
            ed.onKeyUp.add(this.onChange);
        }).createDelegate(this)
        ,apply_source_formatting: false
        ,browserUrl: MODx.config.manager_url+'?a='+MODx.action['browser']
        ,button_tile_map: false
        ,cleanup: false
        ,verify_html : false
        ,compressor: ''
        ,convert_fonts_to_spans: true
        ,convert_newlines_to_brs: false
        ,element_format: 'xhtml'
        ,element_list: ''
        ,entities: '60,nbsp,161,iexcl,162,cent,163,pound,164,curren,165,yen,166,brvbar,167,sect,168,uml,169,copy,170,ordf,'
        + '171,laquo,172,not,173,shy,174,reg,175,macr,176,deg,177,plusmn,178,sup2,179,sup3,180,acute,181,micro,182,para,'
        + '183,middot,184,cedil,185,sup1,186,ordm,187,raquo,188,frac14,189,frac12,190,frac34,191,iquest,192,Agrave,193,Aacute,'
        + '194,Acirc,195,Atilde,196,Auml,197,Aring,198,AElig,199,Ccedil,200,Egrave,201,Eacute,202,Ecirc,203,Euml,204,Igrave,'
        + '205,Iacute,206,Icirc,207,Iuml,208,ETH,209,Ntilde,210,Ograve,211,Oacute,212,Ocirc,213,Otilde,214,Ouml,215,times,'
        + '216,Oslash,217,Ugrave,218,Uacute,219,Ucirc,220,Uuml,221,Yacute,222,THORN,223,szlig,224,agrave,225,aacute,226,acirc,'
        + '227,atilde,228,auml,229,aring,230,aelig,231,ccedil,232,egrave,233,eacute,234,ecirc,235,euml,236,igrave,237,iacute,'
        + '238,icirc,239,iuml,240,eth,241,ntilde,242,ograve,243,oacute,244,ocirc,245,otilde,246,ouml,247,divide,248,oslash,'
        + '249,ugrave,250,uacute,251,ucirc,252,uuml,253,yacute,254,thorn,255,yuml,402,fnof,913,Alpha,914,Beta,915,Gamma,916,Delta,'
        + '917,Epsilon,918,Zeta,919,Eta,920,Theta,921,Iota,922,Kappa,923,Lambda,924,Mu,925,Nu,926,Xi,927,Omicron,928,Pi,929,Rho,'
        + '931,Sigma,932,Tau,933,Upsilon,934,Phi,935,Chi,936,Psi,937,Omega,945,alpha,946,beta,947,gamma,948,delta,949,epsilon,'
        + '950,zeta,951,eta,952,theta,953,iota,954,kappa,955,lambda,956,mu,957,nu,958,xi,959,omicron,960,pi,961,rho,962,sigmaf,'
        + '963,sigma,964,tau,965,upsilon,966,phi,967,chi,968,psi,969,omega,977,thetasym,978,upsih,982,piv,8226,bull,8230,hellip,'
        + '8242,prime,8243,Prime,8254,oline,8260,frasl,8472,weierp,8465,image,8476,real,8482,trade,8501,alefsym,8592,larr,8593,uarr,'
        + '8594,rarr,8595,darr,8596,harr,8629,crarr,8656,lArr,8657,uArr,8658,rArr,8659,dArr,8660,hArr,8704,forall,8706,part,8707,exist,'
        + '8709,empty,8711,nabla,8712,isin,8713,notin,8715,ni,8719,prod,8721,sum,8722,minus,8727,lowast,8730,radic,8733,prop,8734,infin,'
        + '8736,ang,8743,and,8744,or,8745,cap,8746,cup,8747,int,8756,there4,8764,sim,8773,cong,8776,asymp,8800,ne,8801,equiv,8804,le,8805,ge,'
        + '8834,sub,8835,sup,8836,nsub,8838,sube,8839,supe,8853,oplus,8855,otimes,8869,perp,8901,sdot,8968,lceil,8969,rceil,8970,lfloor,'
        + '8971,rfloor,9001,lang,9002,rang,9674,loz,9824,spades,9827,clubs,9829,hearts,9830,diams,338,OElig,339,oelig,352,Scaron,353,scaron,'
        + '376,Yuml,710,circ,732,tilde,8194,ensp,8195,emsp,8201,thinsp,8204,zwnj,8205,zwj,8206,lrm,8207,rlm,8211,ndash,8212,mdash,8216,lsquo,'
        + '8217,rsquo,8218,sbquo,8220,ldquo,8221,rdquo,8222,bdquo,8224,dagger,8225,Dagger,8240,permil,8249,lsaquo,8250,rsaquo,8364,euro'
        ,entity_encoding: 'named'
        ,file_browser_callback: 'Tiny.loadBrowser'
        ,formats: 'p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,div,blockquote,code,pre,address'
        ,frontend: false
        ,height: '400px'
        ,invalid_elements: ''
        ,language: MODx.config['manager_language']
        ,mode: 'none'
        ,nowrap: false
        ,path: Tiny.config.assets_path
        ,path_options: ''
        ,plugin_insertdate_dateFormat: '%Y-%m-%d'
        ,plugin_insertdate_timeFormat: '%H:%M:%S'
        ,relative_urls: true
        ,remove_line_breaks: false
        ,resource_browser_path: Tiny.config.manager_url+'controllers/browser/index.php?'
        ,width: '90%'

        ,buttons1: MODx.config['tiny.custom_buttons1']
        ,buttons2: MODx.config['tiny.custom_buttons2']
        ,buttons3: MODx.config['tiny.custom_buttons3']
        ,buttons4: MODx.config['tiny.custom_buttons4']
        ,css_path: MODx.config['editor_css_path'] || ''
        ,css_selectors: MODx.config['tinymce.css_selectors']
        ,plugins: MODx.config['tiny.custom_plugins']

        ,theme: MODx.config['tiny.editor_theme'] || 'advanced'
        ,theme_advanced_buttons1: MODx.config['tiny.custom_buttons1']
        ,theme_advanced_buttons2: MODx.config['tiny.custom_buttons2']
        ,theme_advanced_buttons3: MODx.config['tiny.custom_buttons3']
        ,theme_advanced_buttons4: MODx.config['tiny.custom_buttons4']
        ,theme_advanced_blockformats: MODx.config['tiny.blockformats']
        ,theme_advanced_resizing: false
        ,theme_advanced_resize_horizontal: false
        ,theme_advanced_statusbar_location: 'bottom'
        ,theme_advanced_toolbar_align: 'left'
        ,theme_advanced_disable: ''
        ,theme_advanced_toolbar_location: 'top'

        ,toolbar_align: MODx.config['manager_direction'] || 'rtl'
        ,use_browser: MODx.config['use_browser'] || true

        ,skin: MODx.config['tiny.skin']
        ,skin_variant: MODx.config['tiny.skin_variant']
        ,object_resizing: MODx.config['tiny.object_resizing'] || true
        ,table_inline_editing: MODx.config['tiny.table_inline_editing'] || true
        ,template_selected_content_classes: MODx.config['tiny.template_selected_content_classes']
    });
    Ext.applyIf(config,{
        width: '90%'
    });
    Tiny.Editor.superclass.constructor.call(this,config);
    this.config = config;
    this.addEvents({
        'load': true
        ,'ajaxload': true
    });
    this.on('render',this.onTinyRender,this);
    this.on('ajaxload',this.onAjaxLoad,this);
};
Ext.extend(Tiny.Editor,Ext.form.TextArea,{
    editor: null

    ,getTinyId: function() {
        return this.getEl().dom.id;
    }

    ,setValue: function(v) {
        var c = tinyMCE.get(this.getTinyId());
        if (c) c.setContent(v);
    }

    ,onTinyRender: function() {
        var oid = Ext.get(this.getTinyId());
        if (!oid) return;

        var s = this.config.tinyConfig;
        s.mode = 'exact';
        tinyMCE.init(s);
        tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', false,this.getTinyId());
        this.fireEvent('load');
    }

    ,onChange: function() {}
    ,onLoad: function(ed) {
        return false;
        var el = Ext.get(ed.id+'_ifr');
        new MODx.load({
            xtype: 'modx-treedrop'
            ,target: el
            ,targetEl: el.dom
            ,iframe: true
            ,iframeEl: 'tinymce'
            ,onInsert: function(v) {
                tinyMCE.execCommand('mceInsertContent',false,v);
            }
        });
    }
    ,onAjaxLoad: function() {
        var els = Ext.query('.modx-richtext');
        Ext.each(els,function(el,i) {
            el = Ext.get(el);
            tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, el.dom.id);
        },this);

        this.fireEvent('ajaxload');
    }
    ,toggle: function(e,t) {
        t = t.id.replace(/-toggle/,'');
        ed = tinyMCE.get(t);
        if (ed) {
            ed.isHidden() ? ed.show() : ed.hide();
        }
    }

    ,loadBrowser: function(fld, url, type, win) {
        tinyMCE.activeEditor.windowManager.open({
            file: this.config.browserUrl || Tiny.config.browserUrl
            ,width: screen.width * 0.7
            ,height: screen.height * 0.7
            ,resizable: 'yes'
            ,inline: 'yes'
            ,close_previous: 'no'
        },{
            window: win
            ,input: fld
        });
        return false;
    }
});
Ext.reg('tinymce',Tiny.Editor);
```